# How to read in an entire binary blob in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to read in the entire contents of a binary file.  Similar to the following Python code:

```
with open("Male_Moose.jpg") as f:
  data = f.read()

  print "Length of file: ", len(data)
```

And this is my R code:

```
main <- function()
{
  fname <- "Male_Moose.jpg"
  contents <- readBin(fname, file.info(fname)$size)

  cat(paste("File size:     ", nchar(contents, type = "bytes")))
  cat("\n\n")
  cat(paste("File info size:", file.info(fname)$size))
  cat("\n\n")
}

main()
```

The JPG file is about 1.2 megabytes.  The Python code reads in the file correctly as a blob and I can find its length in-memory.  R does not do things the same way.  Why is this?

[edit]

The output of the R script:

```
File size:      20

File info size: 1261900
```

Comment: Can you give some more evidence? What does `file.info(fname)$size` return? And what about `nchar(contents, type = "bytes")`? Also the default data type is "interger" when using `readBin`. Did you want `mode="raw"` to read the bytes? Try reading the `?readBin` help page.

Comment: Hi Flick, the reason why I want to read in the entire binary is because I want to compute the hash of that file and stuff that into a hashmap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You left out the 2nd argument to `readBin`, which is the *type* of data you want to read:

```
readBin(con, what, n = 1L, size = NA_integer_, signed = TRUE,
        endian = .Platform$endian)
```

Specify what as `"raw"`, which will read the data as a vector of raw bytes:

```
contents <- readBin(fname, "raw", file.info(fname)$size)
length(contents)  # not nchar()
```

Answer (score 2):

You may find it easier to use the jpeg package.

```
library(jpeg)
MooseImage = readJPEG("Male_Moose.jpg")
```

and then if you just want a blob

```
MooseBlob = as.vector(MooseImage)
```